# Can't update model with mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i'm trying to make an update functionality but it doesn't update the model :( First i make a get request to get the data from the server and populate it in form(handlebars)

so, here's the router:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const warum = await Warum.findById(req.params.id)
    res.render('edit', warum);
});

router.post('/edit/:id', (req, res) => {
    return Warum.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, { new: true }, {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
    })
        .then(() => {
            res.redirect('/warum');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

that's the form:

```
<form method="post">
    <h2>Beitrag bearbeiten</h2>
    <ul class="noBullet">
        <li>
            <label for="title">Titel:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" value="{{title}}" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="description">Beschreibung:</label>
            <textarea class="texterea" name="description">
                {{description}}
            </textarea>
        </li>
        <div>
            <button class="login-button">save</button>
        </div>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and that's the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const WarumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    
});
const Warum = mongoose.model('Warumschema', WarumSchema);
module.exports = Warum;
```

I tried to change the route from post to put, but then it says 404. After clicking the save button it just redirects me, but the result is not edited.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nowhere in this code you are trying to update the model? You are trying to update an instance of the model, a document.

Changing POST to PUT indeed won't help because you do not have a PUT route. Just a GET/POST. Hence it gives a 404.

The reason your POST might not work is because the order of arguments of findOneAndUpdate is wrong. See here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Basically you need to do

```
return Warum.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
    }, { new: true })
```

So the { new : true } needs to tb